# What are the best html5 based charting packages you have used?

Tags: html, canvas

Requirements:

- List item
- entirely client-side (except maybe conversion to image)
- export to image
- able to print chart
- user interactivity (hover annotation)
- multiple axis
- price < $300 per site
- IE6/7/8 compatibility *optional*

I've looked at the following:

- List item
- Highchart
- rGraph
- Zingchart
- infoVis toolkit
- jQuery Flot
- Protovis
- jqPlot

Which would you recommend based on your (or your team's) experiences?

Considering the following aspects:

- List item
- ease of use/learning curve
- ease of extension/customizability
- range of available charts/themes, aesthetics
- level of support/buginess

Answer (score 1):

Not to be a pain and sidestep you, but - and I say this as a Canvas lover - the best charting package I've used is gRaphael, which uses SVG/VML and not Canvas.

http://g.raphaeljs.com/

You tagged this as "canvas" and "html5" only but gRaphael fulfills most of your requirements. It is especially easy to use, and the learning curve is better, as SVG generally requires a lot less code to get a rich user experience than Canvas-based libraries do.

[Here is the plugin for exporting-to-image for raphael-based apps](http://www.benbarnett.net/2010/06/04/export-svg-from-raphael-js-to-create-a-png-bitmap/)

I'm not sure about the printing situation, but since it is SVG you ought to be able to print with less fuss than if you were using Canvas, but I don't think raphael has anything additional built in to deal with printing.

Of course, using SVG means that performance will suffer more if you plan on making a highly complex/large app with lots of animation and interactivity, but that is pretty unlikely in the world of charting, unless you're trying to win a "most nauseating way to present information" award or something.

I earnestly think you should start prototyping your app with gRaphael first. You should be able to get something up quicker than with a Canvas library which will let you evaluate fairly quickly whether it will be a good fit or not.

Answer (score 1):

@Xerion - I'm on the [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com) team. Zing should fit the bill pretty well, as it renders in HTML5 Canvas, SVG, VML, and/or Flash for compatibility and various scenarios. Simon had a great point about SVG -- more complex charts (data, features or otherwise) tend to cause SVG to fall behind Canvas in performance. See different scenarios here http://www.zingchart.com/#speedtest.

Feel free to contact me abegin[at]zingchart.com with  any questions, or mention/follow us at twitter.com/zingchart.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are building a saas application then Zing is terribly expensive.  They wanted to charge per processor and server.

Comment: @MichaelKMadison We actually don't charge by processor or server. Where did you get that infomation? Glad to chat to clear it up if you'd like.

Comment: I was evaluating charting options and could not get pricing without noting the number of servers and processors.  I mentioned that I obviously don't want to pay based on servers or some variable number (unless we are talking about domains), etc.  But because it is a SaaS product it's based on some formula, etc.

Comment: Please explain your pricing transparently if this is a mistake.  Most people here are building SaaS applications (they are developers). Currently, our website requires inquiry for SaaS applications and only has transparent pricing for non-software websites ($249) and non-software multiple websites ($999).